# Anylogic - How to provide different interpolation for two different data under the same plot?

Tags: plot, anylogic

I have a plot with two different data values. I need one of the data to be plotted in the form of steps and the other linear. 
The problem is that, I can change the form of the plot altogether (i.e. I can plot both the data values either as steps or linear), but cannot do so for each data value there are (i.e. I cannot plot one of the data value's in steps and the other in linear form, under the same plot).
I could not find hints to the solution of the problem,in the anylogic manual. Does anyone know how could I do as mentioned or even a reference if there is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are hitting a limitation in Anylogic, as far as i can see. when that happens the answer is usually using plain old java, to get the result you want. 
the way i usually do it, is by creating a new window in java; a **JFrame**. Since adding custom java object to the anylogic window is a bit difficult. 
I would suggest reading up on Java, but your code should look something like this:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph window");
// Creating a chart using JFreeChart: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/ 
XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
JLabel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
chartpanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
frame.getContentPane().add(chartpanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

You will have to download and import the JFreeChart library to use it.

- You can download it from here: [free.org](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html)
- to import it into anylogic. goto the settings of your main-object -> "advance java" and add something like: `import org.jfree.*;`

And you will also have to tune the graph for your purpose and add data to your dataset, but there are plenty of tutorials on the internet for that.